# Multi page pdf using fop-one page for each person tag

Tags: xml, pdf, xsl-fo

I need to convert my xml data using xsl-fo template into pdf using fop.
My XML data looks like.

```
<resultset>
<person>
</person>
<person>
</person>
<person>
</person>
</resultset>
```

Each of the person tags need to go into a separate page in the pdf. Can
somebody please guide me with a sample xsl-fo template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will get you started, depending on what information is in the person tag.

```
<xsl:template match="person">
    <fo:block page-break-before="always">
         process the contents of the person tag here
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Some background info:
[XSLT](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp)
[XSL-FO](http://w3schools.sinsixx.com/xslfo/xslfo_intro.asp.htm)
[XSL-FO 2](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect3/xsl-fo.html)

Comment: Do I need to use a foreach loop in my xsl.

Comment: No. The template match will be called every time the processor encounters a <person> node.

Answer (score 2):

Two alternatives:

- Use `break-before="page"` on the FO that you generate from `person`. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#break-before.)
- Start a new `fo:page-sequence` for each `person`. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_page-sequence.)